# res.render parameters boolean always returns undefined in Async

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a problem where the boolean parameters always returns an undefined,

```
Async.parallel([
  //List the trashed job
  function(callback){
    Jobs.find({"isTrashed":true},function(err, jobs){
     if(err){
       callback(err);
     }
       callback(null, jobs);
    });
  },

],
```

From the async results, the delete_action always returns an undefined

```
//Finish
function(err, results){
  return res.render('jobs/jobs', { delete_action: true, //Undefined (?)
                                   draft_view:req.session.draft,
                                   trash_view:req.session.trash,
                                   jobs:results[0],
                                 });
  });
}
```

When I try to use the `if` built in helper from handlebars, it does not go through the block, because it always returns with an undefined

Here is the **jobs.hbs** file

```
{{log delete_action}}
{{#if delete_action }}
  <div style="padding-top: 3px" class="row-actions">
    <span><a href="#">Restore</a>&nbsp;<font style="color: #DDDDDD">|    </font></span>
    <span><a href="/delete-job?id={{_id}}" style="color:     #AA0000">Permanently Delete</a>&nbsp;<font style="color: #DDDDDD">|</font>   </span>
  </div>
{{else}}
  <div style="padding-top: 3px" class="row-actions">
    <span><a href="/edit-job?id={{_id}}">Edit</a>&nbsp;<font style="color: #DDDDDD">|</font></span>
    <span><a href="#">Quick Edit</a>&nbsp;<font style="color: #DDDDDD">|</font></span>
    <span><a href="/delete-job?id={{_id}}" style="color: #AA0000">Trash</a>&nbsp;<font style="color: #DDDDDD">|</font></span>
    <span><a href="#">View</a>&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
 {{/if}}
```

Comment: You should probably also at least include the relevant portion of your `jobs/jobs` template.

Comment: @mscdex Hi, i dont quite get what you are saying, but on the views folder, i have another folder called `jobs`and inside, i have a `jobs.hbs` file. Something like this `/views/jobs/job.hbs` EDIT: `jobs.hbs` snippet

Comment: I don't know how sensitive handlebars is to whitespace, but did you try removing the trailing space after `#if delete_action`?

Comment: @mscdex Hi, i've tried deleting the whitespace but it still returns an undefined. I don't think that is the problem, since I have some helpers that leaves a whitespace Ex: `{{if_eq job_status "draft" }}`, which still works

Comment: Which handlebars module are you using and what version?

Comment: @mscdex Hi, it is the `express-handelbars` version 3.0.0. This is very confusing, because it should be easy and straight-forward.

Comment: @mscdex Hi, here is my full hbs file http://pastebin.com/Ww3vAnbE, so I have an `each` loop outside the `if`'s. If I log the if outside the each, it returns true, if I log the if inside the each, it returns and undefined. The problem is I need to access it inside the each, do you know how?